# Binding a function to the MouseDown event in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

im Working on learning WPF and C# programming at the moment but im struggling with understanding bindings etc.

I am stuck on "binding" functions or commands to my XAML object which is in a grid.

```
<Image x:Name="BlkRook1" Source="../Data/BlkRook.png" Grid.Row="{Binding Path=ChessPieces[0].Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=ChessPieces[0].Column}" MouseDown="{Binding Path=ChessPieces[0].Move()}"/>
```

The code `MouseDown="{Binding Path=ChessPieces[0].Move()}"` Does not work but displays what im trying to achive

In my viewmodel i have defined a list which i have filled up with instances of my diffrent chesspieces, and then im planning on binding each image to a instance from that list.

im trying to do is bind the MouseDown function at the moment, it seems like if i place the function in the Mainwindow.xaml.cs file it can access it. But i want it to be able to access it from the model

**Mainwindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace TheGame.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window   
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ChessBoardViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

The BlkRook object has defined Row, column, name and a function move at the moment.

**Error Message:**

"'TheGame.Views.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Move' and no extension method 'Move' accepting a first argument of type 'TheGame.Views.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

So.. How do i bind a function that is defined in a Model-object to a XAML object?

Thanks

/Martin

Comment: Why not bind the View command to a new ViewModel method which then invokes Move from the appropriate Model object?  Thus: View-ViewModel-Model

Comment: @bland Wouldn't this scream i.e. `A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'AddMouseDownHandler' property of type 'Border'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't bind to methods. You are using MVVM so I would suggest you to use attached properties in combination with commands.  You could also use the MouseBinding class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebinding(v=vs.110).aspx.
<strike>Commandbinding is explained quite well here: http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/</strike>

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseDownCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link really explains alot.

Comment: Unfortunately, within the command, there is no way to get a reference to the `Button` any more. Also, where are the arguments of the `MouseDown` event, such as an indication of which button was pressed (without resorting to 3rd-party libraries as the one mentioned in the linked article)?

Comment: you can use the `CommandParameter` property of the `InvokeCommandAction`.