# What event(s) trigger a command in a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, command

so i have a question relating to a project i'm working on:

what events are used to trigger a command in a button control? is it only the click event?

because when i click on a button my command will be executed after my mouse button is released? so thats why i want to know.

```
<Button x:Name="ClickButton" Content="Click here" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="325,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ClickHereCommand}"/>
```

Code in the ViewModel

```
  public ICommand ClickHereCommand => (new CommandHandler(() => IsGoingUp(), _canExecute));

    public void IsGoingUp()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Moving up...");
    }
```

Comment: Click even will be fired when you will actually click. What you are looking for?

Comment: @Anand, added code behind, when i click on the button and hold it down, the console writeline will be executed after i release my mouse button

Comment: Wpf - read about [routed events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx), tbh I don't know exact sequence, but it's for sure mouse down + mouse up events with check what coordinates stay same and perhaps (I don't know) time check. That would prevent most of wrong scenarios to detect click: e.g. releasing pressed outside left mouse button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Command property is indeed bound to the Click event. You can bind your Command property to other events as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356042/1166719.

Though if you just want to bind your Command to another mouse event, the ClickMode property is what you're looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so Click event is the only event that is bound to the command property?

Comment: I just edited my answer a few moments ago, with the ClickMode property. But yes, the Command property is bound to either of the three ClickMode members (Hover, Press or Release).

Comment: ahh oke and by default it is Release i assume?

Comment: Indeed (it's written in the ClickMode MSDN article ;)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i will check it out!:)

Answer (score 0):

Events are raised in relation to a controls state. That is, when a button is clicked, or when a mouse moves over it etc.

If you want a list of the available events, in the designer, select the button then bring up properties (F4). Then click the lightning button in the properties window. This will list all the events for the selected control. You can also create methods for handling these events from here.

Here is a list of events for a button control

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button_events(v=vs.110).aspx