# Binding a command and DragEnter and Drop events in the same button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, icommand

In my WPF MVVM (NET 3.5) app I have below button:

```
<Button AllowDrop="True"  
        Drop="btnDelete_Drop" 
        DragEnter="btnDelete_DragEnter"
        Content="Delete"/>
```

The button behavior is the following:

- If some listview items are drag and drop on this button, then some event in the view are raised btnDelete_DragEnter" and "btnDelete_Drop". On drop, the dropped items are removed by calling a method in the view model from the view.

Now, I want to control the click event on the button and I would like to use a Command for only this event.

So my question is:

Is there any way to associate a command only for click event and keep the rest of events as above, through Drop and DragEnter events?

It seems like It can be done using Prism (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122823/how-to-trigger-viewmodel-command-for-a-specific-button-events)) by importing below reference:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

But my problem here is that it is not compatible with WPF .NET 3.5 ... so any other way to do it without using Prism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to associate a command only for click event and keep the rest of events as above, through Drop and DragEnter events?

Yes. This is exactly what the `Command` property of the `Button` is for. Bind this property to an `ICommand` property of your view model:

```
<Button Command="{Binding YourCommandProperty}" />
```

You will need an implementation of the `ICommand` interface. Prism provides one called `DelegateCommand` but you could define your own one. Please refer to the following blog post for more information: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/. It includes a sample implementation.

Comment: Yes, right! By default command is bound to the click event ;) see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508556/what-events-trigger-a-command-in-a-button

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use the Command property....

```
<Button AllowDrop="True"  
        Drop="btnDelete_Drop" 
        DragEnter="btnDelete_DragEnter"
        Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
        Content="Delete"/>
```

and in your ViewModel implement an ICommand called ClickCommand